# Action Man book for children that had very adult death scenes

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in the mid 1990's. It was sold as part of a children's gift bag (a bag that contained a book, some sweets, some stickers and some toys). The book was probably only around 150 to 200 pages long.

The book was marketed as linked to Action Man but the only real link seemed to be the logo on the front page.

The story involves a group of soldiers who need to attack an enemy in a bunker/base in a jungle setting.

The base is surrounded by a electric fence that needs to be breached to allow the soldiers to attack.

The book would have been aimed at teenage children (10-12 years old), but had some quite brutal deaths that were not age appropriate.

Some soldiers were mauled by guard dog's, some were electrocuted by the fence and others were blown up by grenades.

The book was part of a series of similar stories.

The front cover of the book was mainly white with I think a purple band at the top and bottom of the page. There was an image of a cartoon like soldier on the front cover with a 6-wheeled buggy being driven by another soldier.

Comment: I think those deaths would have been age-appropriate as long as they were bloodless. The various animated *Star Wars* shows have similar material and those are rated 6+.

Comment: From what I remember they weren't bloodless and were described in detail or the aftermath/remains were. I always thought it was a pulpy adult book that they slapped an action man logo on

Comment: Was it a comic book or "normal" book?  Commando and Battle (two childrens-orientated WW2 focused comics) were always quite graphic in terms of deaths, as in they were definitely part of the action and you saw them happen, and these were prolific in the 1980s and 1990s - they were available as both self contained single story books and as annuals or Christmas editions.  Then of course you had Victor, Eagle etc which were all of a similar ilk.

Comment: It was a fully written book with no pictures. I was the thinking it could be a repurposed story from one of those comics as I feel that the link to action man was very weak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now found my version of the book and can confirm that it is the story [Death in the Jungle](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/e/jim-eldridge/death-in-jungle.htm) written by Lee James, the pen name for [Jim Eldridge](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/e/jim-eldridge/).

My description of the front cover was slightly off (the colour bands are different and then vehicle is 4 wheeled and not six). The version I have had a sticker like image, that's says "This edition produced exclusively for Action Man".

I believe Action Man in this instance was the children's gift bag in which I got the book.

[image: book cover]